# CefSharp C# change navigator.appName for javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Sorry about my english!

In JavaScript and CefSharp browser this code always return "Netscape":

`<html>
    <head>
        <title>appName</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <script>
            alert(navigator.appName);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>`

Does has any way to change the value in CefSharp settings to my e.g. "MySuperScape"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm doesn't believe that it can be easily changed without altering chromium/blink code.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/NavigatorID.cpp&q=appName&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=49

If you need to identify your browser application, then you can change user agent. If you provide custom JS API in your browser then you can test them, that should be even better than relying on user agent. Otherwise this doesn't looks like have sense.